# Why is the parsing only happening on the first item of each table

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm new to python and web scraping and I would kindly like some advice. I have created the spider however the json output only provides the first element of each table. Can anyone let me know what is the reason for it?

```
import scrapy

class ActaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'acta_spider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.fcf.cat/acta/2022/futbol-11/cadet-primera-divisio/grup-2/1c/la-salle-bonanova-ce-a/1c/lhospitalet-centre-esports-b']
    
    def parse (self, response):
        for actaelements in response.css('table.acta-table'):
            try:
              yield {
                'name' : actaelements.css('a::text').get(),
                'link' : actaelements.css('a').attrib['href'],
            }
            except:
              yield {
                'name' : actaelements.css('a::text').get(),
                'link' : 'Link Error',
            }
```

My ultimate goal is to create a JSON file that creates for each table the necessary information:

```
{
  "DadesPartit":
    {
      "Temporada": "2021-2022",
      "Categoria": "Cadet",
      "Divisio": "Primera",
      "Grup": 2,
      "Jornada": 28
    },
  "TitularsCasa":
    [
      {
        "Nom": "IGNACIO",
        "Cognom":"FERNÁNDEZ ARTOLA",
        "Link": "https://.."
      },
      {
        "Nom": "JAIME",
        "Cognom":"FERNÁNDEZ ARTOLA",
        "Link": "https://.."
      },
      {
        "Nom": "BRUNO",
        "Cognom":"FERRÉ CORREA",
        "Link": "https://.."
      }
      
    ],
  "SuplentsCasa":
    [
      {
        "Nom": " MARC",
        "Cognom":"GIMÉNEZ ABELLA",
        "Link": "https://.."
      }
    ],
  "CosTecnicCasa":
    [
      {
        "Nom": " JORDI",
        "Cognom":"LORENTE VILLENA",
        "Llicencia": "E"
      }
    ],
  "TargetesCasa": 
    [
      {
        "Nom": "IGNACIO",
        "Cognom":"FERNÁNDEZ ARTOLA",
        "Tipus": "Groga",
        "Minut": 65
      }
    ],
  "Arbitres":
    [
      {
        "Nom": " ALEJANDRO",
        "Cognom":"ALVAREZ MOLINA",
        "Delegacio": "Barcelona1"
        
      }
    ],
  "Gols":
    [
      {
        "Nom": "NATXO",
        "Cognom":"MONTERO RAYA",
        "Minut": 5,
        "Tipus": "Gol de penal"
      }
    ],
  "Estadi":
    {
      "Nom": "CAMP DE FUTBOL COL·LEGI LA SALLE BONANOVA,
      "Direccio":"C/ DE SANT JOAN DE LA SALLE, 33, BARCELONA"
    },
    "TitularsFora":
    [
      {
        "Nom": "MARTI",
        "Cognom":"MOLINA MARTIMPE",
        "Link": "https://.."
      },
      {
        "Nom": " XAVIER",
        "Cognom":"MORA AMOR",
        "Link": "https://.."
      },
      {
        "Nom": " IVAN",
        "Cognom":"ARRANZ MORALES",
        "Link": "https://.."
      }
      
    ],
  "SuplentsFora":
    [
      {
        "Nom": "OLIVER",
        "Cognom":"ALCAZAR SANCHEZ",
        "Link": "https://.."
      }
    ],
  "CosTecnicFora":
    [
      {
        "Nom": " RAFAEL",
        "Cognom":"ESPIGARES MARTINEZ",
        "Llicencia": "D"
      }
    ],
  "TargetesFora": 
    [
      {
        "Nom": " ORIOL",
        "Cognom":"ALCOBA LAGE",
        "Tipus": "Groga",
        "Minut": 34
      }
    ]
}
```

Thanks,
Joan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS selectors return a list of matching elements.  Since there is only one element that matches your query the for loop only executes once and retreives the first link only.  One minor adjustment you could make is using xpath you can select all of the children of the table and your code should work as expected.

Simply change your for loop to:

```
for actalements in response.xpath('//table[@class="acta-table"]/*'):
```

And the rest of your code should work the way you would expect.

Comment: Hi **Alexpdev** thanks for the answer. My idea is to get all the elements in the 12 tables. I need to filter out some elements differently. For example, there are some elements which are under **class white oswald tc p-r z-0 w-44px** but others simply **class tc**

Comment: @futbolbasecelh Im glad my answer helped you.  What you are asking now is a different question than the original and one I would be happy to help you with if you open a new question on SO.

Comment: **alexpdev** should I copy the same original question and just request an ask for the additional help?

Comment: @futbolbasecelh  ask the a new question include your code from this question plus any updates you have made, and then repeat what you put in your comment above as the question

Comment: @futbolbasecelh  I just noticed that you edited your question... yah you can just copy and paste but you can leave out the part that I answered and include the description from the your comment above

Answer (score 0):

It happens because your css selector is wrong, it's just for the table and not the items. Also you can remove the `try except` and give the link a default value if it's "None".

```py
import scrapy


class ActaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'acta_spider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.fcf.cat/acta/2022/futbol-11/cadet-primera-divisio/grup-2/1c/la-salle-bonanova-ce-a/1c/lhospitalet-centre-esports-b']

    def parse(self, response):
        for actaelements in response.css('table.acta-table tbody tr'):
            yield {
                'name': actaelements.css('a::text').get(),
                'link': actaelements.css('a::attr(href)').get(default='Link Error'),
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. To make sure I understand it correctly. With the change you have mentioned, you are selecting all the tr elements for table with class acta-table. Is my understanding correct?